# sql redshift: Create table with pairs based on one column values plus the number of purchases (events) of each combination

Tags: sql, combinations, amazon-redshift

I have a table with two columns: product and client.
I need to create all pairs between the products and add a third column with the number of clients buying both products of that pair.

Example:

```
clients product
001 pants
001 shirt
001 pants
002 pants
002 shirt
002 shoes
```

I would need to reorder the products in tuplas and add a third column with the number of unique clients who bought the two products. So the previous example, the outcome would be:

```
product1 product2 count
pants shirt 2
pants shoes 1
shirt shoes 1
```

I would like to avoid duplicated information. For example a row 'shirt pants 2' would not be needed.

Would someone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you have duplicates, so this could get messy.

The simple ways is a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, count(distinct t1.client)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.product = t2.product 
group by t1.product, t2.product;
```

This could get very expensive thought, particularly if there are many duplicates.

One alternative is to use `distinct` before doing the `join`:

```
select pc.product, pc2.product, count(*)
from (select distinct product, client from t) pc
     (select distinct product, client from t) pc2
     on pc2.client = pc.client and pc2.product < pc.product;
```

Comment: Thank you but in your first example on t1.product = t2.product would give me same product in one row. Did you mean on t1.client= t2.client?

Comment: This returns almost what I need. The only thing missing would be the condition of avoiding duplicates: I would like to avoid duplicated information. For example a row 'shirt pants 2' would not be needed.